# Change Image on image click event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am not able to change image on clicking image in jquery
pls see this

```
$("#signin").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("show data");
    $("#signin").Attr('src', 'images/icon.png');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#signin").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("src", "images/icon.png");
});
```

.attr <- Function name is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
.Attr
```

to

```
.attr
```

.Attr is not a function in jQuery, it's case sensitive.

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

**Note:** You could use `this.src` there is no need to use jQuery to change the source of the image

```
$("#signin").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("show data");
    this.src= 'images/icon.png';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mis-spelled the function [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). The `Attr` should be `attr`, javascript is **case sensitive**.

```
$("#signin").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("show data");
    $("#signin").attr('src', 'images/icon.png');
});
```